# Skrollr Excessively Jerky

Tags: performance, frontend, skrollr

I've been working on a Skrollr site but it appears to be getting excessively jerky. I've had dev tools open and have found a few really really slow frames, but I don't have the knowledge to track down exactly what is going wrong.

[image]

My observations are:

- it is slower scrolling down than up
- intermittently it is absolutely fine

So far I have tried a few things

- Given the first segment a translateZ value to try and separate out the paint (I have no idea if this is correct – I'm really at the limit of my knowledge!)
- Had a go getting rid of the relative animations (data-top-bottom etc) which could well be slowing things down, but after changing everything back to static numbers (data-1000 etc) its still almost identical

Can anyone shed any light on this? The URL is http://fieldviewfestival.co.uk/500 ... power up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've fixed it!

The webfonts weren't fully loaded when skrollr kicked in. After initializing it I added a

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

Where I refreshed skrollr I then added the following:

```
s.refresh();
```

I think the main problem was that the height of the page wasn't calculated by the time skrollr kicked in.

Also I had a strange scrollbar left over (so a scrollbar on the body AND html), which skrollr hadn't removed so I also added above that function

```
 $(window).trigger('resize');
```

The final initialize looks like this:

```
var s = skrollr.init();

$(window).load(function(){
    // console.log("Loaded");
    $(window).trigger('resize');
    s.refresh();
});
```

**NB** Silly miskate I made as well, don't use the function `$(document).load(`